# Shall we request that code syntax highlighting be enabled?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

A portion of our questions are related to SDK usage and contain code snippets in the target language. For example:

- [tx_bad_seq error when funding the account](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/questions/2285/tx-bad-seq-error-when-funding-the-account)
- [How to catch specific error code on JS SDK connecting to horizon](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/questions/2252/how-to-catch-specific-error-code-on-js-sdk-connecting-to-horizon)
- [Transaction Stream parameter and method not recognized](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/questions/1994/transaction-stream-parameter-and-method-not-recognized)
- [How to decode stellar XDR](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/questions/1912/how-to-decode-stellar-xdr)

These do not have syntax highlighting applied, because highlighting is enabled on sites only after it is requested and approved.

Should we request that code syntax highlighting be enabled for the Stellar StackExchange site?

Comment: I think the title of the meta post could be clarified to "syntax highlighting" instead of "code formatting", because I thought it was about the code block itself...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes please! Although can the syntax highlighting autodetect different languages?

Comment: Once enabled for the site, I or another mod will be able to associate tags to language syntax.